# How to select one drop down list using capybara

Tags: ruby, capybara

I have 2 drop down lists in 2 different forms.
My html code:

```
<form id = "frm1">
  <select name="time_zone" class="time_zone chosen">
     <option value="International Date Line West">(GMT-11:00) International Date Line West</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

And:

```
<form class="new-user">
  <select name="time_zone" class="time_zone chosen">
     <option value="International Date Line West">(GMT-11:00) International Date Line West</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

I want to select ddl in frm2, but I don't know how to select that.
Can somebody please help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
within '.new-user' do
  select 'Something', from: 'time_zone'
end
```

Comment: @beginerdeveloper, you can use any selector as an argument for `within`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one liner using capybara:

```
page.find('.new-user .time_zone option', :text => 'something').click
```